# Magento configurable product slow with strace showing thousands of stat calls to /usr/share/zoneinfo

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento, ubuntu

After creating a Configurable Product with roughly 120 associated products, the product page is incredibly slow to load with the Apache2 worker process spiking to 100% CPU usage. After rolling back code a few times to ensure this was nothing new that our dev team pushed, I decided to have a closer look with `strace` and was a bit shocked to find *thousands* of blocks in the output file containing the following (the query string changes, but the `stat` are always the same)

```
12:50:28.374278 write(23, "\202\0\0\0\3SELECT `main_table`.* FROM "..., 134) = 134
12:50:28.374316 read(23, "\1\0\0\1\23>\0\0\2\3def\7magento\nmain_table"..., 16384) = 1519
12:50:28.374567 brk(0x7ff7f7786000)     = 0x7ff7f7786000
12:50:28.374825 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.374864 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.374934 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.374972 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.375039 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.375078 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.375140 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.375180 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.375239 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3519, ...}) = 0
12:50:28.375278 stat("/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
```

This was recorded using:

`$ sudo strace -Ff -tt -p <pid> 2>&1 | tee strace-apache2.log`

The request ran for about 36 seconds and resulted in over 110k `stat()` calls:

```
$ head -n2 strace-4-apache2.log 
Process 23220 attached - interrupt to quit
12:39:16.025656 poll([{fd=23, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
$ tail -n1 strace-4-apache2.log 
12:39:52.365977 poll([{fd=22, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000

$ cat strace-apache2.log | grep -i "stat.*zoneinfo" | wc -l
110274
```

System Information is as follows:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

$ php -v
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.14 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2014 07:08:49) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jul 22 2014 14:35:25
```

Any input or pointers on troubleshooting this would be great, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enabling query logging via the Varian MySQL adapter, I discovered that a module installed along-side a recent theme update was responsible for about 6k out of the 21k queries logged by the profiler while loading the configurable product page with ~200 associated products. All of these queries involved date calculations, hence the numerous calls to the system's timezone information. After disabling said module (MageGiant, particularly the Daily Deals extension), there is a major improvement in performance.

Before:

```
$ grep -i "stat.*zoneinfo" strace-beforeModuleDisable-apache2.log | wc -l
110274
```

After:

```
$ grep -i "stat.*zoneinfo" strace-afterModuleDisable-apache2.log | wc -l
1082
```

Considering this resolved now, I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your technique helped me find similar issues with other nasty third party modules.

Comment: @james.c.funk glad I could help!